# Graphics driver problem in loki

Tags: graphics

Recently I have done **Elementary Loki** installation. I feel, screen little bit shaking for every action/windows opening time. 
I am facing the same issue while playing any video. while playing the videos its struck frequently. I have already installed graphics driver.

And what are the mandatory things I should do after the fresh installation of OS?

Can anybody help me on this?

Thanks in Advance
Vinoth

Answer (score 1):

Nothing mandatory per sé, however google for "things to do after installing elementary" to get some useful tips on what to do.

regarding graphics driver I'd recommend to install and test out different (compatible) versions.

The app called "Additional Drivers" is nice for seeing all installed drivers and selecting one of them to use. You can get it from the AppCenter.

Keep in mind though that fiddling with graphics drivers is always a bit risky, make sure your data is backed up.